# Graphics in Java; Update frame without flashing screen

Tags: java, graphics

I wrote some code that draws a line at the center of a `JPanel`. The line is constantly redrawn to point at the user's cursor from within a `mouseMoved` action listener.

Everything seems to work fine expect that after moving the cursor around for a while, the line being redrawn starts flashing and becomes completely inconsistent.

Is this flashing caused by the poor performance of my PC or by the `clearRect()` method being the 'wrong' thing to use?

These two reasons above wouldn't explain why the flashing only starts after a certain amount of moving the cursor around.

Please, feel free to run the code below and let me know whether the line starts flashing for you:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    int x;
    int y;

    public Frame1() {
        initComponents();
        x = jPanel1.getWidth()/2;
        y = jPanel1.getHeight()/2;
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseDragged(evt);
            }
            public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MouseMoved(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1000, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 680, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }

    private void jPanel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    

    private void jPanel1MouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0,jPanel1.getWidth(), jPanel1.getHeight());
        g.translate(x, y);
        g.drawLine(
                0,
                0,
                (int)(120*Math.cos(Math.atan2(evt.getY() - y, evt.getX() - x))),
                (int)(120*Math.sin(Math.atan2(evt.getY() - y, evt.getX() - x)))
        );
    }                                  

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {

        Frame1 frame = new Frame1();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I suspect that there is a better way to update the position of the line and redraw it without calling `clearRect()` and if you know one, I'd love to know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();` this is NOT how painting in Swing is done.  You've circumvented the double buffering support that is otherwise provided by Swing components.

Instead, create a custom `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method (making sure you call `super.paintComponent` before you to do any custom painting) and perform your painting there.

Within your custom `JPanel`, add your `MouseListener` to it and when `mouseMoved` is triggered, update the state variables you need (the point of the last point and the mouse point) and call `repaint`

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting should be done